# Mock Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, internationalization

I am working on a function that compares two timezones. I pass a timezone to the function and the other timezone is the timezone I get from `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`. Everything works as expected, and in the browser I can spoof the timeZone by changing the location sensor, see:

[image]

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns-tz'

export const isSameTimeZone = (eventDate, eventTimeZone) => {
  const userTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone

  if (eventTimeZone === userTimeZone) return true

  const userOffset = format(new Date(eventDate), 'XXX', { timeZone: userTimeZone })
  const eventOffset = format(new Date(eventDate), 'XXX', { timeZone: eventTimeZone })

  return userOffset === eventOffset
}
```

After creating the function I started writing tests in Jest. Everything works as expected so far, but at this point I would like to mock the `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` because I would like to test what happens if the timezone if the user is different, for example `Asia/Tokyo`. I'm a bit new to mocking stuff in Jest, anyone knows how I can achieve this?

Testcases:

```
expect(isSameTimeZone(new Date('2021-04-01T00:00:00+02:00'), 'Europe/Amsterdam')).toBeTruthy() // true
// Spoof user timezone
expect(isSameTimeZone(new Date('2021-04-01T00:00:00+02:00'), 'Europe/Amsterdam')).toBeFalsy() // should return false
```

Comment: I just have one thing to add, I suspect you need to specify the language you want from Intl.DateTimeFormat() or else you might have different languages in the two things you're trying to compare, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat